# XSLT Transformation of a SOAP Response with multiple namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, xml-namespaces

I have been trying to transform a SOAP Response, based on my knowledge I have tried many approaches, below is the XML and XSL I have written, I can't seem to get any node's value.

Below is the xml :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
  <CreateCallResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <CreateCallResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceCallCreate" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:ParameterList>
           <a:Paramname>errorstate</a:Paramname>
           <a:ParamValue>0</a:ParamValue>
        </a:ParameterList>
        <a:ParameterList>
           <a:Paramname>errorstring</a:Paramname>
           <a:ParamValue/>
        </a:ParameterList>
        <a:ParameterList>
           <a:Paramname>newcallid</a:Paramname>
           <a:ParamValue>160901-0083</a:ParamValue>
        </a:ParameterList>
     </CreateCallResult>
  </CreateCallResponse>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Below is the XSL :

```
 <xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
  xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope"
  xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceCallCreate"
  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:k="http://tempuri.org" exclude-result-prefixes="s k i a">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <CreateCallResponse>
        <ErrorCode>
             <xsl:value-of select="s:Envelope/s:Body/k:CreateCallResponse/i:CreateCallResult/a:ParameterList/a:ParamValue" />
        </ErrorCode>
    </CreateCallResponse>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help me out on where I have done the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the stylesheet you have not used the URIs from the input so change `xmlns:k="http://tempuri.org"` to `xmlns:k="http://tempuri.org/"` in the stylesheet and `xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope"` to `xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` as well, then change the path to `<xsl:value-of select="s:Envelope/s:Body/k:CreateCallResponse/k:CreateCallResult/a:ParameterList/a:ParamValue" />`. I am not sure however which `ParamValue` from the input you want.

Comment: I have tried this too, but am not getting any value. From what i understand the above xpath should bring me the first paramValue